# Sort the array based on other array values in JavaScript or jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

i have an array list which has to be sorted based on other 3 array values. i was successfully able to sort with one array but have no idea on how to proceed with remaining arrays. Please correct if my logic is wrong.

```js
let result = [
 {"name" : "two", "sports" : "football", "prize" : "first"},
 {"name" : "two", "sports" : "cricket", "prize" : "first"},
 {"name" : "two", "sports" : "cricket", "prize" : "second"},
 {"name" : "three", "sports" : "football", "prize" : "first"},
 {"name" : "one", "sports" : "football", "prize" : "first"},
 {"name" : "three", "sports" : "cricket", "prize" : "second"},
 {"name" : "one", "sports" : "cricket", "prize" : "second"},
 {"name" : "one", "sports" : "cricket", "prize" : "first"},
]
 
 let norder = ["one", "two", "three"];
 function courseSort(a, order, key) {
 const map = order.reduce((r, v, i) => ((r[v] = i), r), {})
 return a.sort((a, b) => map[a[key]] - map[b[key]])
 } 
result = courseSort(result, norder, `name`);  
console.log(result)
```

My other two arrays are

```
let nsports = ["cricket", "football", "chess"];
let nprize = ["first", "second"];
```

in addition to sorting based on one array value on first item "name", Keep it the same the other items  needs to be sorted and re-ordered. Expected Output as below

```
[
{"name" : "one", "sports" : "cricket", "prize" : "first"},
{"name" : "one", "sports" : "cricket", "prize" : "second"},
{"name" : "one", "sports" : "football", "prize" : "first"},
{"name" : "two", "sports" : "cricket", "prize" : "first"},
{"name" : "two", "sports" : "cricket", "prize" : "second"},
{"name" : "two", "sports" : "football", "prize" : "first"},
{"name" : "three", "sports" : "cricket", "prize" : "second"},    
{"name" : "three", "sports" : "football", "prize" : "first"},    
]
```

the first level sort should freeze the field name and second level on sports and third level on prize

please suggest a way to find solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with `sort`.

```js
var result = [ {"name" : "two", "sports" : "football", "prize" : "first"}, {"name" : "two", "sports" : "cricket", "prize" : "first"}, {"name" : "two", "sports" : "cricket", "prize" : "second"}, {"name" : "three", "sports" : "football", "prize" : "first"}, {"name" : "one", "sports" : "football", "prize" : "first"}, {"name" : "three", "sports" : "cricket", "prize" : "second"}, {"name" : "one", "sports" : "cricket", "prize" : "second"}, {"name" : "one", "sports" : "cricket", "prize" : "first"},];
let nsports = ["cricket", "football", "chess"];
let nprize = ["first", "second"];
let norder = ["one", "two", "three"];

var sortedarray = result.sort((a,b)=>{
    return norder.indexOf(a.name) - norder.indexOf(b.name) || nsports.indexOf(a.sports) - nsports.indexOf(b.sports) || nprize.indexOf(a.prize) - nprize.indexOf(b.prize)
});

console.log(sortedarray)
```

Since you have other array defined, you can just check for index position according to type with an or condition(for multiple sort) and then sort on the basis of that.

Comment: Great, thank you for the support and explaining stuff :)